# How to hook audio stream from kernel?

Tags: windows, audio

I would like to know how to hook audio stream from kernel using ReadEx(). Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via any sane method. Please tell us what you actually want to do and perhaps we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My requirement is when the user selects the option 'play at remote system' over RDP the audio which runs through player at terminal server should be played at client with low latency. Is there any way for programmatically redirecting the audio from player to client before writing to the local sound card buffer?